# Is there a way to edit the text of a specific label in a grid layout?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, grid-layout

I need to update the text of different labels throughout the program.

Example: If my grid layout is (12,12) and I need to change the texts of a label at (2,5) how can I do this?

Maybe even a way to erase the label and add a new one at the same position.

Comment: Are they all JLabels? Or are they various types of components?

Answer (score 1):

Create a 2D array of `JLabel`

```
JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[12][12];
// populate and add to container with GridLayout(12, 12)
...
// change property
JLabel label = labels[2][5];
label.setText(..)
```

---

> "Maybe even a way to erase the label and add a new one at the same position."

No need, just change the properties of the existing one

---

**UPDATE**

See example here. Pay close attention to the method `createButtonsPanel`. Its where I access the label from the grid.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestLabelGrid {

    public TestLabelGrid() {
        JLabel[][] labelGrid = createLabelGrid(6, 6);
        JPanel labelPanel = createPanel(labelGrid);
        JPanel buttonPanel = createButtonsPanel(labelGrid);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        frame.add(labelPanel);
        frame.add(buttonPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel(JLabel[][] labels) {
        int rows = labels.length;
        int cols = labels[0].length;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
        for (JLabel[] rowOfLabels: labels) {
            for (JLabel label : rowOfLabels) {
                panel.add(label);
            }
        }
        return panel;
    }

    private JLabel[][] createLabelGrid(int rows, int cols) {
        JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                labels[i][j] = new JLabel("( " + i + " , " + j + " )");
            }
        }
        return labels;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel(final JLabel[][] labels) {
        int rows = labels.length;
        int cols = labels[0].length;
        JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[rows][cols];
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                String text = "( " + i + " , " + j + " )";
                JButton button = new JButton(text);
                buttons[i][j] = button;
                final int jTemp = j;
                final int iTemp = i;
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JLabel label = labels[iTemp][jTemp];
                        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                });
                panel.add(button);
            }
        }
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new TestLabelGrid();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I just explained it. If you're gridlayout it 12 by 12 and you want 2,5 then use the labels[2][5]. Other than that you need to explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Piemaster316  see this example in the **UPDATE**

Comment: Finished my java final thanks to the help of you guys! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference to each of your Labels, or [perhaps use container.getComponents()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29), but I am unsure if that method has any guarantee on the order of the components in the array.

To swap components, you can instead add a container at each of the locations of the GridLayout, and change what component the container at that position contains.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do. Could you give example of what the code would look like?

Comment: Code example showing what, saving a reference to a bunch of labels? You can store them in an array like peeskillet's answer. If you want to swap components, you can store instead a reference to a container containing the label, and remove the label and add a new label (same add/remove you always use on a container), but unless these are custom label classes that change from one to another, I would just change the state of each label instead.